# Helm Charts - How do I use `default` on undefined object property values?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Using Helm, I was under the impression `default` would be the fallback if a variable is not defined. However, it doesn't appear Helm can get to values in sub-object hashes:

```
  type: {{ default "NodePort" .Values.fpm.service.type }}
```

If `.Values.fpm.service` or `service.type` is not defined, it should use 9000.

However, attempting to template this throws a nil pointer error:

```
 <.Values.fpm.service.type>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.type
```

Is there a way to simply perform this level of variable testing? Or am I subjected to an if/else test?

The intent of this is to *optionally* define `.fpm.service` (and `[..].type`) within your `values.yaml` file.

(I'm building a Helm Library chart to handle optional definitions by main charts)

Answer (score 9):

According to the [official Helm doc (Using Default Function)](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-default-function), the syntax is different and you should use it this way:

```
type: {{ .Values.fpm.service.type | default "NodePort" | quote }}
```

Comment: That's not it, though. The issue isn't around default. The issue is around Helm trying to go down into a non-existing object: checking for "fpm.service.type" and not just stopping when "fpm.service" doesn't exist.

Comment: PS: The docs to clearly state this is an expected argument approach, too: `default DEFAULT_VALUE GIVEN_VALUE`

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: .Values.nonexiting | default "a default" will work. .Values.nonexisting.nonexting2 | default "default" will not. Due to the fact that "nonexisting" does not exist and Helm cant then go deeper

Comment: There's an option to wrap it with brackets for example:


type: {{ ((.Values.fpm).service).type | default "NodePort" | quote }}

Answer (score 6):

Doesn't look like there's really a good way to stop Helm from trying to dive into non-existing objects. I moved into a single line if condition, and it worked:

```
  type: {{ if .Values.fpm.service -}} {{ .default "NodePort" .Values.fpm.service.type | quote }} {{- else -}} "NodePort" {{- end }}
```

This way, I check if `fpm.service` exists first, before trying `.type` check. It works, whether `.service` and `.service.type` is or is not defined.

Comment: You are correct, non existing objects are being traversed, at least we have to define them with empty values.

Answer (score 2):

In Helm we can wrap a value that we might consider optional in brackets.

```yaml
type: {{ (.Values.fpm.service).type | default "NodePort" }}
```

Now when we try to run a helm template / install, it will consider `.Values.fpm.service` to be optional. We would still run into a Nil pointer if `.Values.fpm` is not set. So you must ensure to encapsulate up until where should be considered optional, as you can see in the example I provided, I did not place brackets around `.type` otherwise, it would try to find `service` which may not exist.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/68807258/7598776