# How to make nested variables optional in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

How do I make an optional block in the values file and then refer to it in the template?

For examples, say I have a values file that looks like the following:

```
# values.yaml
foo:
   bar: "something"
```

And then I have a helm template that looks like this:

```
{{ .Values.foo.bar }}
```

What if I want to make the foo.bar in the values file optional? An error is raised if the `foo` key does not exist in the values.

I've tried adding as an if conditional. However, this still fails if the `foo` key is missing:

```
{{ if .Values.foo.bar }}
{{ .Values.foo.bar }}
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Most charts will default the parent object to an empty map in `values.yaml` so it always exists and first level checks `{{ if .Values.foo.bar }}` will work.

```
foo: {}
```

Test each key in order with parenthesis (added from [Torrey's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68807258/1318694) better solution):

```
{{ if ((.Values.foo).bar) }}
bar: {{ .Values.foo.bar }}
{{ end }}
```

Use the `and` function (helm 3.10+/go 1.18+ thanks
@nicolauscg)

```
{{ if (and .Values.foo .Values.foo.bar) }}
bar: {{ .Values.foo.bar }}
{{ end }}
```

There is also the `hasKey` function included from [sprig](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html) if you ever need to check the existence of a falsey or empty value:

```
{{ if hasKey .Values.foo "bar" }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the hasKey approach before, but didn't have the default `foo: {}` set. I'll give that another shot.

Comment: Is it possible to cleanup/re-write the following in a cleaner way?

`{{ if hasKey .Values.global "rabbitmq" }} {{ .Values.global.rabbitmq.password | b64enc | quote }} {{ else }} {{ $def.RABBITMQ_PASSWORD | b64enc | quote }} {{ end }}`

Comment: @Justin I'm not sure how that applies to the nested key issue? You could this as a separate question

Comment: Note that the `and` function has changed to short circuit since go1.18 https://go.dev/doc/go1.18, so using `and` is also an option on newer helm/go version

Answer (score 121):

#### Simple workaround

Wrap **each nullable level** with parentheses `()`.

```
{{ ((.Values.foo).bar) }}
```

Or

```
{{ if ((.Values.foo).bar) }}
{{ .Values.foo.bar }}
{{ end }}
```

#### How does it work?

Helm uses the go `text/template` and inherits the behaviours from there.

Each pair of parentheses `()` can be considered a `pipeline`.

From the doc (https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Actions)

It is:

> The default textual representation (the same as would be printed by fmt.Print)...

With the behaviour:

> If the value of the pipeline is empty, **no output is generated**... The empty values are false, 0, **any nil pointer or interface value**, and any array, slice, map, or string of length zero.

As such, by wrapping **each nullable level** with parentheses, when they are chained, the predecessor nil pointer gracefully generates no output to the successor and so on, achieving the nested nullable fields workaround.

Comment: Cheers; this seems to work great. Where'd you find it? I'm struggling to find any docs for it

Comment: it doesn't work for me, which helm version do you use?

Comment: Can confirm it's working on our use case, but would be great to know why it works? I also have not found any docs on why/how the parentheses change the `nil` behavior.

Comment: @JameelA. Thanks for confirming. The usage is not documented in the Helm unfortunately. It is the syntax implicitly documented in the go `text/template`. I have added some references and a brief explanation. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: @ZimbiX Thanks! I originally read this usage from a Github issue and just remembered it. Couldn't find the original thread anymore :(. I have added some reference from the go. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: @PeterJurkovic I'm using Helm 3.6.3. It should work the same for all Helm 3. Never tested on Helm 2. But the behaviour is inherited from the go template :)

Comment: This is genius! I am iterating over a list and this allows me to default on missing subkeys for each element. I am using Helm 3.9.x

Comment: OMG! This is great, a null-safe-coalescer... sort-of
I had been trying to use [dig](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#dig) for this, but it's totally useless and ugly having to use strings

Comment: Is there any advantage of
    {{ if ((.Values.foo).bar) }}
    x: {{ .Values.foo.bar }}
    {{ end }}
over
    {{ with .Values.foo }}
    x: {{ .bar }}
    {{ end }}
?

Comment: @riemann The parentheses `()` allows us to inline **unlimited** nullable nested level, while the `with` on its own requires **one** per nullable condition. If preferable, you can combine the parentheses and the with, to specify the unlimited nullable nested scope.

Comment: This works great, thanks. The fact this is necessary makes me want to run naked around town screaming.

Answer (score 18):

A technique I've used successfully is to use a variable to hold the value of the outer block, which then can use templating constructs like `default` and Sprig's [dict](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html) helper.

```
{{- $foo := .Values.foo | default dict -}}
Bar is {{ $foo.bar | default "not in the values file" }}
```

This provides a fallback dictionary if `foo` isn't in the file, so then `$foo` is always defined and you can look up `$foo.bar` in it.

Answer (score 18):

### Use `with`

Look at the [`with` operator](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#modifying-scope-using-with).  This limits the current scope to the level of `.Values.foo`, and the block is silently ignored if `.foo` is missing:

```
{{- with .Values.foo }}
  {{- .bar }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Can confirm, works as advertised. I would accept this as the real answer.

Comment: There are always some cases you have to use `if`, e.g., when you need an `else`. Actually, that would be super great for `with` to come with an `else`.

Answer (score 7):

There is a new function implemented in sprig called `dig` that just does fix this issue, see here http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html .

Is not yet released so even less likely to be in helm soon.

Meanwhile I have modified @Samuel solution to mimic the new dig function.

```
{{- define "dig" -}}
  {{- $mapToCheck := index . "map" -}}
  {{- $keyToFind := index . "key" -}}
  {{- $default := index . "default" -}}
  {{- $keySet := (splitList "." $keyToFind) -}}
  {{- $firstKey := first $keySet -}}
  {{- if index $mapToCheck $firstKey -}} {{/* The key was found */}}
    {{- if eq 1 (len $keySet) -}}{{/* The final key in the set implies we're done */}}
      {{- index $mapToCheck $firstKey -}}
    {{- else }}{{/* More keys to check, recurse */}}
      {{- include "dig" (dict "map" (index $mapToCheck $firstKey) "key" (join "." (rest $keySet)) "default" $default) }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- else }}{{/* The key was not found */}}
      {{- $default -}}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

and you can call it like this

```
$regKey := include "dig" (dict "map" .Values "key" "global.registryKey" "default" "")
```

Comment: It seems to me that the dig function might land in helm in January (the new sprig has already been released and the [merge request](https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/9126) for helm has already been accepted; next feature release for helm is [scheduled for Jan 13](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v3.4.2))

Answer (score 3):

I searched around for an answer to this same question, and couldn't find anything out there.  It seems you have to use a custom function, so I wrote one.  Here is what I came up with.  It works for my use cases, feedback/improvements are welcome.

_helpers.tpl

```
{{- define "hasDeepKey" -}}
  {{- $mapToCheck := index . "mapToCheck" -}}
  {{- $keyToFind := index . "keyToFind" -}}
  {{- $keySet := (splitList "." $keyToFind) -}}
  {{- $firstKey := first $keySet -}}
  {{- if index $mapToCheck $firstKey -}}{{*/ The key was found */}}
    {{- if eq 1 (len $keySet) -}}{{*/ The final key in the set implies we're done */}}
true
    {{- else }}{{*/ More keys to check, recurse */}}
      {{- include "hasDeepKey" (dict "mapToCheck" (index $mapToCheck $firstKey) "keyToFind" (join "." (rest $keySet))) }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- else }}{{/* The key was not found */}}
false
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

values.yaml:

```
    {{- if eq "true" (include "hasDeepKey" (dict "mapToCheck" .Values "keyToFind" "foo.bar")) }}
      bar: {{- .Values.foo.bar }}
    {{- end }}
```