# Check existence of nested object in Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I've got these values in a YAML file:

```
configuration:
  files:
  - from: "foo.yml"
    to: "bar.yml"
```

I would like to check whether `configuration` and `files` exists like this:

```
{{- if and .Values.configuration .Values.configuration.files -}}
volumeMounts:
  {{- range .Values.configuration.files -}}
  - name: "config"
    mountPath: {{ .to }}
  {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

It works beautifully when `configuration` and `files` exist but when both are omitted I get this error when rendering the Helm template:

> Error: render error in "chart/templates/deployment.yaml": template: chart/templates/deployment.yaml:62:48: executing "chart/templates/deployment.yaml" at <.Values.configuration.files>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.files

How can I check whether both exist without nesting two `if`clauses?

Comment: what version of helm are you using

Comment: both 2.15 and 3.1 but a solution for any of them would be fine.

Comment: I was tempted to write an answer but this fits the scenario.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59795596/helm-optional-nested-variables/68807258#68807258